# How to run this plugin every time a post is saved?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, tags, save-post

So far this is what I have... I'm new to developing plugins so I'm not sure how to make a plugin run code on a post save. I know that this would likely work if it was added to the post.php page but I want to do it as a plugin, eventually with a box of CSV on a settings page to create the array I manually defined here. The goal is to tag every post that names a city with that city's tag. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Auto Post Tagger
 * Plugin URI: http://www.sitecrafters.pro/plugins/auto-tagger.zip
 * Description: The very 13th plugin that I have ever created.
 * Version: 1.10
 * Author: Cody King
 * Author URI: http://sitecrafters.pro
 */

/**
 * @snippet       Auto Post Tagger
 * @author        Cody King
 * @compatible    Wordpress 6.4.3
 */
  
  
function autotag( $post_id ) {
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
        {
            if(StrPos($post_id > the_content(),$keyword))
            {
                $keyword = str_replace(' ','-',$keyword);
                wp_set_post_tags($post_id,$keyword);
            }
        }
}

$keywords = ['Los Angeles','New York','Chicago','Houston','Phoenix']
add_action( 'save_post', 'autotag' );
?>
```

Edit #6: After some sleep and a clearer head I saw what was wrong with the syntax. This is the newest version below... It lets me activate it and has no error messages but it doesn't seem to do anything when I save posts or publish them. Am I missing a step? Do I need to run `save_post` in this function after I use `wp_set_post_tags`?

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Auto Post Tagger
 * Plugin URI: http://www.sitecrafters.pro/plugins/auto-tagger.zip
 * Description: The very 13th plugin that I have ever created.
 * Version: 1.13
 * Author: Cody King
 * Author URI: http://sitecrafters.pro
 */

/**
 * @snippet       Auto Post Tagger
 * @author        Cody King
 * @compatible    Wordpress 6.4.3
 */


function autotag( $post_id ) {
    foreach ( $keywords as $keyword )
        {
            $keycheck = StrPos( get_the_content(), $keyword );
            if( $keycheck === true )
            {
                $keyword = str_replace( ' ' , '-' , $keyword ); // Convert spaces to dashes "-"
                wp_set_post_tags( $post_id , $keyword , true ); // Set tags to Post
            }
        }
}

$keywords = ['Los Angeles','New York','Chicago','Houston','Phoenix'];
add_action( 'save_post', 'autotag' );
```

Comment: `the_content` does not return the posts content, it `echo`'s it out so you can't use it to do `if` statements or checks, take a look at `get_the_content`. Likewise it doesn't know _which_ post to get the content for so it might fetch the wrong one.You also don't need it, the post being saved is the second argument of that action, see: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/

Comment: THanks. I get what you mean and appreciate the nudge in the right direction. Can you tell me how to activate this function with a plugin? The error it's throwing at me is saying that "add_action" is causing the problem. If so, what do I use to call it without editing my theme files?

Comment: Can you include the error message in your question? I expect it’s unlikely to be related to plugins and more likely to be syntax errors. Are you writing this code yourself or is AI helping you?

Comment: Now it is allowing me to activate the plugin but it is saying "returned 2 unexpected characters" when I activate it.. and it doesn't seem to do anything. I realized I had it backwards and corrected the syntax but no luck.

Comment: Remove the `?>` at the end of the code -- it's not needed. It's possible there are whitespace characters like tabs or spaces after the `?>` which might cause the "unexpected characters" warning/error.

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing that but it's still doing it for some other reason.

Comment: there's no need to call `get_the_id()` to get the post ID, it's being passed in as an argument so it's already set. Also can you copy paste the errors instead of describing them? Errors usually mention file names and line numbers pointing out exactly where the problem happened

Comment: I'm currently getting no errors but it doesn't work either. Do I have to run save_post in the function for it to update the tags?

Comment: It looks as though your `$keywords` are outside of the function so `foreach ( $keywords as $keyword )` has nothing to run a `foreach()` on.  Try putting the `$keywords` array in the function right above the `foreach()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the advice from every awesome person who helped, I finally got it to work. I just had to define `$the_content` instead of trying to use the hook `get_the_content()` alone. Now it's tagging everything perfectly. Here is the final code for anyone who wants to use it in the future. Or you can just download my plugin when I'm finished making it. It will be free.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Auto Post Tagger
 * Plugin URI: http://www.sitecrafters.pro/plugins/auto-tagger.zip
 * Description: The very 13th plugin that I have ever created.
 * Version: 1.15
 * Author: Cody King
 * Author URI: http://sitecrafters.pro
 */

/**
 * @snippet       Auto Post Tagger
 * @author        Cody King
 * @compatible    Wordpress 6.4.3
 */


function autotag( $post_id ) {
    $keywords = ['Los Angeles','New York','Chicago','Houston','Phoenix'];
    $the_content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
    foreach ( $keywords as $keyword )
        {
            $keycheck = strpos( $the_content, $keyword );
            if( $keycheck !== false )
            {
                $keyword = str_replace( ' ' , '-' , $keyword ); // Convert spaces to dashes "-"
                wp_set_post_tags( $post_id , $keyword , true ); // Set tags to Post
            }
        }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'autotag' );
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I suspect what's happening is that you have your `$keywords` array outside the function.  So when the function runs the `foreach()` it has nothing to iterate through, so does nothing.

Try putting the `$keywords` inside the function before the `foreach()`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Auto Post Tagger
 * Plugin URI: http://www.sitecrafters.pro/plugins/auto-tagger.zip
 * Description: The very 13th plugin that I have ever created.
 * Version: 1.13
 * Author: Cody King
 * Author URI: http://sitecrafters.pro
 */

/**
 * @snippet       Auto Post Tagger
 * @author        Cody King
 * @compatible    Wordpress 6.4.3
 */


function ck_autotag_save( $post_id ) {
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) :
        return $post_id;
    endif;
    $the_post = get_post( $post_id );
    $keywords = ['Los Angeles','New York','Chicago','Houston','Phoenix'];
    foreach( $keywords as $keyword ) :
        $keycheck = strpos( $the_post->post_content, $keyword );
        if( $keycheck === true ) :
            $keyword = str_replace( ' ' , '-' , $keyword ); // Convert spaces to dashes "-"
            wp_set_post_tags( $post_id , $keyword , true ); // Set tags to Post
        endif;
    endforeach;
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'ck_autotag_save' );
```

I think that if you're having an error it's most likely that the issue is with `$keycheck` not returning true.  Is it possible that having `StrPos` in camelcase is the issue?  Try running it as `strpos()` instead. Also, I don't think your `get_post_content()` is returning anything. I just tested it in a similar context and got nothing.  When I tried to add just a post ID, that didn't fix it.  I've re-written that segment above.

The function to save the tags to the post when the post is saved looks correct. So I think the most likely issue is that your `$keycheck` is returning false and I've added a few things to solve that.

Comment: I tried this and it's still not tagging anything when I save it. Is the function getting the $post_id from the save_post hook? I'm still a little unclear about how it works.

Comment: I just compared your function above to a function I use to save metadata to posts, everything except for the `wp_set_post_tags()` part is pretty much the same.  I've edited my answer above.

Comment: The `$post_id` is passed along from the function - so this function SHOULD only be run if the `$post_id` is present.  The action hook is saying 'run this when saving a post' and so the function brings the post ID over when it's declared.  The post ID is persistent and one should always be present if 'save_post' is being executed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation that helped a lot. Unfortunately the code you provided didn't work for me but your advice did.